# splitting trapezoid in given proportion

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rounding

I need to split trapezoid in 2 part of given size with line, parallel basement. I need to get new h1 of new trapezoid. 
For example I have trapezoid of area S and I want to split it in 2 trapezoids of areas S1 and S2.

```
S1 = aS; S2 = (1-a)S;
S1 = (a+z)*(h1)/2;
S2 = (b+z)*(1-h1)/2;
S1/S2 = KS;
```

[image]

To get new h1 I compare a and b, `if a != b`, I solve square equation and `if a == b` I work like with square. But sometimes I get mistakes because of rounding (for example when I solve this analytically I get a = b and program thinks a > b). How can I handle this? Or maybe there is another better way to split trapezoid?
Here is simplifyed code:

```
if (base > base_prev) {
    b_t = base; // base of trapezoid
    h = H; //height of trapezoid
    a_t = base_prev; //another base of trapezoid
    KS = S1 / S2;
    a_x = (a_t - b_t) * (1 + KS) / h;
    b_x = 2 * KS * b_t + 2 * b_t;
    c_x = -(a_t * h + b_t * h);
    h_tmp = (-b_x + sqrt(b_x * b_x - 4 * a_x * c_x)) / (2 * a_x);
    if (h_tmp > h || h_tmp < 0) 
        h_tmp = (-b_x - sqrt(b_x * b_x - 4 * a_x * c_x)) / (2 * a_x);
} else if (base < base_prev) {
    b_t = base_prev;
    a_t = base;
    KS = S1 / S2;
    a_x = (a_t - b_t) * (1 + KS) / h;
    b_x = 2 * KS * b_t + 2 * b_t;
    c_x = -(a_t * h + b_t * h);
    h_tmp = (-b_x + sqrt(b_x * b_x - 4 * a_x * c_x)) / (2 * a_x);
    if (h_tmp > h || h_tmp < 0) 
        h_tmp = (-b_x - sqrt(b_x * b_x - 4 * a_x * c_x)) / (2 * a_x);
} 
else {
    KS = S1 / S2;
    h_tmp = h * KS;
}
```

Comment: So do I understand this correctly - the approach works analytically, but there are some issues with accuracy?

Comment: @Codor, It is a part of big program, and the aim of that program is rotate figures and split them in with lines, parallel axises. It works correctly analitically, but sometimes when I rotate figure there are some small rounding mistakes (for example before rotation a = b and after rotation a = b + 10^(-5) ) and when I try to solve this in my program I get very big a_x and it gives enourmously big h_tmp;

Comment: If `a` and `b` are parallel, would it be feasible to rotate the trapezoid to be axis-parallel and perform the transformation there? Would it furthermore be possible to merge the two cases in the code into just one case?

Comment: @Codor in my code the trapezoid is axis perpendicular, so I don't think it is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with catastrophic cancellation, one approach, dating back to [a classic article by Forsythe](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/66/40/CS-TR-66-40.pdf), is to use the alternative solution form x = 2c/(-b -+ sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) for the quadratic equation ax^2 + bx + c = 0. One way to write the two roots, good for b < 0, is

```
x = (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/(2a)
x = 2c/(-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)),
```

and another, good for b >= 0, is

```
x = 2c/(-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))
x = (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/(2a).
```

Alternatively, you could use the [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to obtain a reasonably good guess and polish it with [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).